# Removing parent class when double click on submit button

Tags: jquery, validation

*When i put wrong input and submit form its showing error message and adding class to parent but when i clicked again on submit button, its removing parent class (not error message).
so i don't want to remove the parent class if error message is showing.*

***Below is the code***

Where validation error coming I am adding one class to his parent(i.e. Invalid-input) and applying CSS to label and input field (i.e. making red color and red border).So i put jquery in variable because i am using it multiple times in single file.

```
var addValidation = function(currentSelector){
    $(currentSelector).parents('.form-group').addClass('error-field');
}

var removeValidation = function(currentSelector){
    $(currentSelector).parents('.form-group').removeClass('error-field');
}
```

After that wrote one function to validate input field

```
    function validateinput(){
    var error = 0;
    var ytregex = /^[a-z0-9\/]+$/i;
    var channelName = $(".utube input").val();

    if(channelName.length != 0 && channelName.length < 2 || channelName.length >= 41){        
        $('#ChannelError').html('Channel name length must be between 2 and 40 characters');
        addValidation(this);
        error = 1;
        return error;
    }
    if(ytregex.test(channelName) || channelName == ''){
        $('#ChannelError').html('');
        removeValidation(this);
    }else{
        error = 1;
        $('#ChannelError').html('Invalid Youtube Channel Name');
        addValidation(this);
    }
    return error;
}
```

and put all similar function into one function

```
function validateForm(){ 
   var error = 0;
   error += validateinput();
   return error;
}
```

finally submitting form using ajax and saving data.

Comment: We would need to see your html structure too but my guess is you should only be running the addValidation or `removeValidation` once instead of each validation.  Try at the end (before you return the error) doing if error = 1 add validation else remove validation

Answer (score 0):

On first click the ChannelName becomes 'Invalid Youtube Channel Name'

On second click this code ytregex.test(channelName) is returning true.

Look at your regex.

Comment: actually i was checking code once again and i found that more than on validation is performing on one field (i.e.enter link field ).So when i check on blur its showing error message and adding class to parent but clicking on submit button don't know why its removing  added class on parent..May be on submitting its taking other validation and removing parent class.